# Google Maps API v3 not loading correctly in IE in hidden div with iframe but loads perfectly in all other browsers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Ok I have searched high and low for a solution to this. Everything I have found is not quite working. This is a similar problem to the Google maps not appearing in a hidden div using jquery tabs. However I have the map loading correctly staying loaded and holding the zoom when when navigating to another tab and back in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari.

So my problem as usual is IE.

The way I have set it up is to hide the div initially and then to display it and load in an iframe with the map code in it. As I say it works fine on all but IE where it loads the map in the left hand corner with no resize ability. I'm assuming this is down to the way IE deals with processing javascript. I've tried loads of suggestions on here but all fail in IE so wonder if anyone has come across this before and if any workaround is available.

The code below is to initialise the map. The call to the function is the last thing in page after the closing html tag.

This page is then loaded into a div tag via an iframe when a ui.tab is pressed to change the div panel displayed.

Any clues or tips would be most welcome.

```
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.66416319854267,-1.1316803097724914);

  var myOptions = {
     zoom: 10,
     center: myLatlng,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
     }
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions); 

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  draggable: false,
  position: myLatlng, 
  map: map,
  icon: '../images/yellow-pin.png',
  title: ""
  });
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); // added from another forum post does not work
}
```

Comment: This sounds invalid "The call to the function is the last thing in page after the closing html tag.", there shouldn't be anything after the closing html tag.  But that doesn't mean it won't work.  Can you provide a live example, a jsfiddle, or enough code/html that we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. The site is pre launch but more or less there you can view a page here: http://www.wightislandescapes.com/property-details/548-1 All the code is in the page. If you click through the Tabs above the property you will see it works fine in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari but not IE. Bizarrely it does load in IE7 but does not centre. cheers

Comment: Can you confirm that you have <body onload="initialize()"> in your code to init the function? Also, place this function in the head of your doc for testing with the body init tag.

Comment: Yes it is added but makes no difference to whether the map loads correctly or not.

Answer (score 0):

That is the typical hidden "top left corner" issue.

Have you tried using an onload function to run the initialize function?

The problem is that the javascript code (the trigger "resize") in the iframe is being executed when the page is loaded, not when it is displayed.  When it is loaded the div has zero size.  You need to trigger the resize function on the map after the div is diplayed and has a size.